# How to make XPath text() query case insensitive?

Tags: xpath

I have a query and I'd like it to find any match on a page - regardless if any of the letters on the page are upper or lower case.

My query:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Deez')]
```

I've tried the solutions I've seen given to other similar questions but none have worked. My query uses `text()` which I've not seen in the other questions. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **XPath 2.0 or greater**, you can use [`upper-case()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-upper-case):

```
//*[contains(upper-case(text()),'DEEZ')]
```

or [`lower-case()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-lower-case):

```
//*[contains(lower-case(text()),'deez')]
```

or [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-matches) with the case insensitive flag `i` (won't be the most efficient):

```
//*[matches(text(),'Deez', 'i')]
```

For **XPath 1.0 and greater**, you can use [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-translate) to ensure that all the letters are upper or lower-case:

```
//*[contains(translate(text(), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),'DEEZ')]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer Mads. The last one worked for me in Chrome (I presume they are using XPath 1.0 or similar!

Comment: one quick thing Mads, you missed a letter in your XPath 1.0 answer but I can't edit it as theres too many edits in the stackoverflow queue or something                                     // *[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'Deez')]